# How to compare dataclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I would like to compare two global dataclasses in terms of equality. I changed the field in one of the dataclasses and python still insists on telling me, that those objects are equal. I don't know how internally dataclasses work, but when I print `asdict` I get an empty dictionary... What am I doing wrong and how can I compare dataclasses by checking for equality of its members?

I'm using Python 3.9.4

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class TestClass:
    field1 = None
    field2 = False

test1 = TestClass()
test2 = TestClass()

def main():
    global test1
    global test2

    test2.field2 = True

    print('Test1:        ', id(test1), asdict(test1), test1.field1, test1.field2)
    print('Test2:        ', id(test2), asdict(test2), test2.field1, test2.field2)
    print('Are equal?    ', test1 == test2)
    print('Are not equal?', test1 != test2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Test1:         2017289121504 {} None False
Test2:         2017289119296 {} None True
Are equal?     True
Are not equal? False
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Python to recognize fields of a dataclass, those fields should have [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) type annotations.

For example:

```
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class TestClass:
    field1: Optional[str] = None
    field2: bool = False
```

With that definition comparisons and `asdict` work as expected:

```
In [2]: TestClass(field2=True) == TestClass()
Out[2]: False

In [3]: asdict(TestClass(field2=True))
Out[3]: {'field1': None, 'field2': True}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought those are optional, my bad...

Comment: `==` does not seem to work if you have a super dataclass from which you are inheriting fields.